# Nested f-strings in Python (Third nested f-string)

Tags: python, python-3.x, printing, nested-loops, f-string

I need to convert json to given hcl structure. There is this code:

```py
user_dicts = { 'users': [ {'name': 'test1', 'pass': 'password1', 'permissions': [ {'access': 'yes', 'role': 'admin'}, {'access': 'yes', 'role': 'user'} ] }, {'name': 'test2', 'pass': 'password2', 'permissions': [ {'access': 'yes', 'role': 'admin'} ] } ] }

double_q = '"'

result = f"""
users = [
    {''.join([
    f'''{{
        name        = {double_q}{ d['name'] }{double_q},
        pass        = {double_q}{ d['pass'] }{double_q},
        permissions = [
            {''.join([f"{{ access = {double_q}{ d['permissions'][index]['access'] }{double_q}, role = {double_q}{ d['permissions'][index]['role'] }{double_q} }}," for index in range(len(d['permissions'])) ])}
        ]
    }},
    ''' for d in user_dicts['users']
    ])}
]"""

print(result)
```

which returns the following line:

```
users = [
    {
        name        = "test1",
        pass        = "password1",
        permissions = [
            { access = "yes", role = "admin" },{ access = "yes", role = "user" },
        ]
    },
    {
        name        = "test2",
        pass        = "password2",
        permissions = [
            { access = "yes", role = "admin" },
        ]
    },
    
]
```

What needs to be done so that there is a new line between the dictionaries in permissions while maintaining the number of spaces? That is:

```
users = [
    {
        name        = "test1",
        pass        = "password1",
        permissions = [
            { access = "yes", role = "admin" },
            { access = "yes", role = "user" },
        ]
    },
    {
        name        = "test2",
        pass        = "password2",
        permissions = [
            { access = "yes", role = "admin" },
        ]
    },
    
]
```

I tried adding f-string to new_line variable:

```py
user_dicts = { 'users': [ {'name': 'test1', 'pass': 'password1', 'permissions': [ {'access': 'yes', 'role': 'admin'}, {'access': 'yes', 'role': 'user'} ] }, {'name': 'test2', 'pass': 'password2', 'permissions': [ {'access': 'yes', 'role': 'admin'} ] } ] }

double_q = '"'
new_line = '\n'

result = f"""
users = [
    {''.join([
    f'''{{
        name        = {double_q}{ d['name'] }{double_q},
        pass        = {double_q}{ d['pass'] }{double_q},
        permissions = [
            {f'{new_line}'.join([f"{{ access = {double_q}{ d['permissions'][index]['access'] }{double_q}, role = {double_q}{ d['permissions'][index]['role'] }{double_q} }}," for index in range(len(d['permissions'])) ])}
        ]
    }},
    ''' for d in user_dicts['users']
    ])}
]"""

print(result)
```

But the next line becomes from the beginning of the line:

```
users = [
    {
        name        = "test1",
        pass        = "password1",
        permissions = [
            { access = "yes", role = "admin" },
{ access = "yes", role = "user" },
        ]
    },
    {
        name        = "test2",
        pass        = "password2",
        permissions = [
            { access = "yes", role = "admin" },
        ]
    },
    
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Quick fix

You were on the right track, using the `new_line` variable together with `str.join()`. To maintain the number of spaces, just include them in `new_line`:

```
new_line = '            \n'
```

#### Further thinking

You may want to start using a templating engine, like [Jinja](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/).

**Pros**

- You don't need to concern yourself with (nested) f-strings
- The template string looks like your desired output (kinda WYSIWYG)
- Whitespace control is easy

**Cons**

- You'll probably have to spend some time learning how to use the templating engine

**Your example, implemented with `Jinja`**

To run the following code, you need to install the [`jinja2`](https://pypi.org/project/Jinja2/) package

```
import jinja2

user_dicts = { 'users': [ {'name': 'test1', 'pass': 'password1', 'permissions': [ {'access': 'yes', 'role': 'admin'}, {'access': 'yes', 'role': 'user'} ] }, {'name': 'test2', 'pass': 'password2', 'permissions': [ {'access': 'yes', 'role': 'admin'} ] } ] }

template_str = """
users = [
{% for user in users %}
    {
        name        = "{{ user['name'] }}",
        pass        = "{{ user['pass'] }}",
        permissions = [
{% for p in user['permissions'] %}
            { access = "{{ p['access'] }}", role = "{{ p['role'] }}" },
{% endfor %}
        ]
    },
{% endfor %}

]
""".strip()

template = jinja2.Template(template_str, trim_blocks=True, lstrip_blocks=True)
users = template.render(user_dicts).replace("'", '"')
```

The template string `template_str` is basically your desired output, plus some special tokens (`{% for ... %}`, `{% endfor %}`, `{{ ... }}`). These tokens tell the engine how to "fill in the blanks".

Comment: Thank you. I like your version in Jinja.